# useEffect throws DOMException when using HTMLAudioElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've written a custom React hook called `useAudio` to play sounds in the background of my app.

Why is `useEffect` throwing `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`?

I've narrowed the issue down to the second `useEffect` inside my custom hook. This effect runs when a Boolean indicating whether the audio is `playing` changes.

All React says is `Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.`

I also tried modifying `audio` to be a regular constant instead of declaring via the `useState` hook but that didn't solve it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const useAudio = (url: string) => {
  if (typeof Audio !== 'undefined') {
    const [audio] = useState(new Audio(url))
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false)

    const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing)

    useEffect(() => {
      audio.loop = true
      audio.autoplay = true
    })

    useEffect(() => {
      playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause()
      return () => {
        audio.pause()
      }
    }, [playing])

    return [playing, toggle]
  }
}

const AudioPlayer: React.FC<{ url: string }> = ({ url }) => {
  if (typeof Audio !== 'undefined') {
    const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(url)

    return (
      <AudioContainer>
        {typeof playing !== 'undefined' && (
          <Button onClick={() => toggle()}>
            {playing ? 'Stop music' : 'Play music'}
          </Button>
        )}
      </AudioContainer>
    )
  }
  return null
}

export default AudioPlayer
```

It's working in the [live app](https://mentored.dev/).

it's *not* working in this isolated [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7yxmly6jkx).

I expect the audio to start when the component is mounted and no DOMExceptions to be thrown.

Comment: Not supposed to use hooks in conditionals. From docs / Rules of hooks: `Only call Hooks at the top level. Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @charlietfl! Totally forgot about that.

So you're saying the problem is because I'm calling `useEffect` inside this conditional `if (typeof Audio !== 'undefined')`?

Comment: Not sure...but from what I understand can cause wonky behavior

Comment: You are asking way too much permission on that site of yours, do you really require them all? It made me personally to back off from even trying.

Comment: Btw, there's whole dedicated site on StackExchange portal for reviewing the code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Questions like this are better suited there.

Comment: Also didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com - will post this type of question there next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several vague points about your app, including using hooks in conditional and storing `audio` object in state (try `useRef` instead, that's its only purpose). But the core of the problem it seems that `url` that you feed to `Audio` is `undefined`. I guess CodeSandbox environment doesn't have a proper loader for `mp3` files. Try some direct URL instead.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/l7775jm2rm

Comment: So to solve it, I'll try:
- not using hooks in conditional
- storing `audio` with `useRef`

And you got it working in CodeSandbox. Thanks a bunch @jayarjo!